# Yii Session Timeout and Periodic Server Short Polling

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using short polling in jQuery to periodically (5 mins) check the server for notification updates. I also have a session timeout set on the server after which i would like the user to get automatically logged out. The trouble is that the polling causes the session to extend and the user never gets automatically timed out.

Is there any way in Yii to avoid updating the session for this call alone? Am I missing something?

I am thinking of moving the server side script for this call alone to a standalone PHP script but there would be maintenance overhead associated with this so I am kind of hoping that there is something I can do within Yii to work around this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have a session variable for last time of activity

, every time an activity that counts as an activity, update this

and in case of this special request, don't update this and check if the time period is over, manually log user out and destroy it's session

```
Yii::app()->user->logout();
unset($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is one option I was looking at. But it basically replicates most of what the session management is already doing. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it. Maybe extending CDBbHttpSession or something like that...

Comment: In the end I went with writing a separate standalone PHP script for getting the notification update. I included Yii's config into this script to get the db config so that I can still keep the db config in one place.